# Smallest bag for SD744T

Tags: location, recording

I'm after a location recording bag for my SD744T, and nothing more! All the bags I've looked at sof far seem designed to hold a mixer, recorder and 17 wireless receivers. Can anyone recommend something small and compact?

Answer (score 1):

I think the 744 is the exact size as the 702 (don't take my word for it). If that's the case, you can get the [Sound Devices CS-3 Production Case](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/399052-REG/Sound_Devices_CS_3_CS_3_Production_Case.html).

It does have a pouch at the front, but you can take it off. There's also some extra space at the bottom, but it doesn't affect you as your machine is attached at the top. It's useful if you have a bigger battery, or want to tuck away your excess cable.

If you're only after a bag to carry it, and not for use while recording, then you can get the [CS-MAN Utility Case](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/400234-REG/Sound_Devices_CS_MAN_CS_MAN_Utility_Case.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Portabrace bags for the 7-series recorders, the AR-7.

http://www.coffeysound.com/PortaBrace-AR-7-Audio-Recorder-Case.html

I use it all the time and i don't think it's that bulky + it has some extra space for accessories.

Answer (score 0):

The [Petrol  PS607 Deca (small mixer bag)](http://www.trewaudio.com/store/product.php?productid=1114&cat=0&page=1) is a great "just the recorder" option.  It's smaller than the ads make it appear (in a good way).  You can take off the two small accessory pouches if you don't want them.  The zippered side flaps that allow access to the recorder's controls are made of flexible windbreaker-esque material, so they squish down when empty and add next to zero size to the bag.  An internal divider allows the bag to carry the 744 and/or a small mixer.  It's tinier and more streamlined than the Portabrace equivalents I've seen.